# Explanation of how this code works (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

Can anyone explain me the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace web.frmcolor
{
  public class FormEx : Form
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Set the default color for the designer
    /// </summary>
    static FormEx()
    {
      _globalBackgroundColor = default(Color?);
    }

    private static void InvalidateForms()
    {
      try
      {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < Application.OpenForms.Count; i1++)
        {
          try
          {
            FormEx frm = (Application.OpenForms[i1] as FormEx);
            if (frm != null)
            {
              frm.Invalidate(true);
              frm.Refresh();
            }
          }
          catch 
          { 
            //Should never happen
          }
        }
      }
      catch
      {
        //this will catch if the form count changes
      }
    }

    private static Color? _globalBackgroundColor;
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the background color for all forms
    /// </summary>
    public static Color? GlobalBackgroundColor
    {
      get { return FormEx._globalBackgroundColor; }
      set 
      {
        if (FormEx._globalBackgroundColor != value)
        {
          FormEx._globalBackgroundColor = value;
          InvalidateForms();
        }
      }
    }

    public override Color BackColor
    {
      get
      {
        return (_globalBackgroundColor == null ? base.BackColor : (Color)_globalBackgroundColor);
      }
      set
      {
        base.BackColor = value;
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new colored form
    /// </summary>
    public FormEx()
      : base()
    {
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // FormEx
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
        this.Name = "FormEx";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormEx_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    private void FormEx_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


  }
}
```

Since I am a beginner I am not able to understand how the above coding works. I found this coding while browsing through internet.

The part I don't understand is this:

```
_globalBackgroundColor = default(Color?);
```

Why there is a `?` after the color, what does that indicate?

Comment: Did you try executing the code? That could have given you some insight.

Comment: Yes I executed the code that changes the background of entire application.

Comment: try { FormEx frm = (Application.OpenForms[i1] as FormEx); if (frm != null) { frm.Invalidate(true); frm.Refresh(); } } catch { //Should never happen }  
 AWESOME!!! I hate try{}catch{ //should never happen }

Comment: Hehe, so which part is not clear?

Comment: This part is not clear
 _globalBackgroundColor = default(Color?);
why there is a ? after the color what does that indicate?

Answer (score 3):

The ? means that Color should be Nullable. SInce Color is an Enum, it normally isn't nullable, it is a value type (Check [this](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) out for an explanation of Value Types and Reference Types). Adding the ? means that just in this piece of code the variable can be set to `null`. An explanation of [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx) can be found here.
Furhtermore the `default(Color?)` statement initializes the variable to the default value of `Color?`, which is probably white, or because of the ?, `null`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. 
Then what is the need to use for loop?

Comment: The for loop goes through all Open Forms it can find in the current Application context, then sets the already open Forms' Background Color to the newly selected one. FormEx is a class derived from the standard .NET Framework Windows.Forms.Form class.

Comment: frm.Invalidate and frm.Refresh are called to force what is called a RePaint, that means the Form is rendered again (so the new BackGroundColor will be shown.)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, provide you with a very quick way to change the background of all windows in the application to a common color.

The important part is the private static ... and the public static ...

To change the background of all open form you do:

FormEx.GlobalBackgroundColor = ...some color here..

It will go through each windows belonging to the application and change their the background colors (basically Invalidate will force it to repaint itself).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

But why we are using the question mark :
_globalBackgroundColor = default(Color?);

In the above coding wat does the question mark indicate?

Comment: that denoting that its a nullable type

Comment: Ah... hehe it's a nullable.. So it means that particular variable might be null or contain a value of the type Color